# Cannot get swipe to delete on UITableView cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to get a cell "swipe to delete" action on a cell.

as I've read adding func tableView(
_ tableView: UITableView,
commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
){} method should help, but adding it does nothing.

I've also tried adding canEditRowAt method that always returns true, and implementing editActionsForRowAtIndexPath. but the result is always same the I slide the cell on a simulator nothing happens.

```
class CheckListViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var items = getListItems() // model
    
    let contactsTableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        contactsTableView.dataSource = self
        contactsTableView.delegate = self
        
        contactsTableView.register(CategoryListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "contactCell")

        view.addSubview(contactsTableView)
        
        contactsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contactsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contactsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contactsTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contactsTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}

extension CheckListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryListCell
        cell.label.text = items[indexPath.row].text
        cell.accessoryType = items[indexPath.row].isChecked ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(
      _ tableView: UITableView,
      commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
      forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ){

    }

}

extension CheckListViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            items[indexPath.row].isChecked.toggle()
            cell.accessoryType = items[indexPath.row].isChecked ? .checkmark : .none
        }
          tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        //  you have to delete data at row in getListItems()
        // ex: objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .delete
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, the problem is that I don't get the red delete button when I swipe. Nothing happens on swiping, when it should if I implement the function you wrote. The method is not called so it does not matter what I write inside yet. Thanks.

Comment: Better to read about `Accessibility `

Comment: @SopoKopaliani i did edit it.

Comment: @Ten still did not work :( is it possible that it doesn't work on simulator and should work on device ?

Comment: @MuhammadShauket can you specify what do you mean or how is it connected with this bug.

Comment: please send me your xcode version. I can try it. select Enable User Interaction. check user Interaction enabled. can tableView didSelectRowAt work?

Comment: @Ten Thanks again a lot for helping. The user interaction is enabled. I have a checkmark that gets checked and unchecked every time I press the row. Where can I send you my project? I uploaded it on GitHub https://github.com/sophiekopaliani/Bullseye.git